# Referring a paper which is still under publication

Tags: research-process, peer-review, conference, paper-submission

My domain is Image Processing and Computer Vision.

I've written a follow-up paper for my previous paper which is still not available in IEEE Xplore. I am submitting the new paper in a conference. I want to ask what is the best approach for making the previous paper available to reviewers?

1. Upload the previous paper in arXiv
2. Submit the previous paper as a supplementary material

Please guide me.

Comment: Are you sure that you can upload something at arxiv that is pending for publication in IEEE Xplore? You should look into the IEEE terms.

Comment: @Alexandros: Yes that is possible. Please see: [IEEE's self-archiving policy](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/pub/38/)

Answer (score 4):

I would make a distinction between whether your paper has been presented at a conference and whether it has appeared in IEEE Xplore.

If it has already been presented, then it's out there in the community and, in my opinion, it is entirely reasonable to take advantage of IEEE's self-archiving options and post it on a personal or institutional website where it can be readily found by search engines.  There is no reason to wait for the (sometimes painfully slow) updating of the IEEE Xplore database.

If it has yet to appear, however, then I would recommend instead attaching it as supplementary material, if possible.

Comment: As I've mentioned in question, my paper is still not available in Xplore (it was presented in a conference in November 2015). So better to attach as supplementary material (possible)?

Comment: @stalin Actually, since you already presented it, I recommend that you simply post your pre-print publicly online following [IEEE's self-archiving policy](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/pub/38/)